# Adding an item to a HornetQ queue from a servlet

Tags: java, jboss, hornetq, jboss-eap-6

I have a project that gets built as a war file and deployed to a JBOSS server. The JBOSS server's standalone-full-ha.xml file is configured to create several queues. The war file uses Spring to register a class to listen to these queues, and process the messages it gets. The application that normally puts messages on the queue is written by another vendor; I don't have visibility into what that code is like. However, I need to be able to add messages to the queue in my dev environment for testing purposes.

I wrote a small servlet and added it to the war to attempt this test. However, I'm getting an exception when I call the servlet:

```
13:54:12,211 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to create remoting connection [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeExcept
ion: Operation failed with status WAITING]
13:54:12,211 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)      at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.ClientUtil.namingException(ClientUtil.java:36)
13:54:12,211 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)      at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactory.java:121
)
13:54:12,211 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)      at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
13:54:12,226 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)      at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
13:54:12,226 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)      at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:242)
13:54:12,226 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)      at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
13:54:12,226 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)      at com.me.me.servlets.SingleFileImportServlet.doGet(SingleFileImportServlet.java:75)
13:54:12,226 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
13:54:12,226 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
13:54:12,226 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
13:54:12,226 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
13:54:12,226 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
13:54:12,226 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
13:54:12,242 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)      at org.jboss.modcluster.container.jbossweb.JBossWebContext$RequestListenerValve.event(JBossWebContext.ja
va:67)
13:54:12,242 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)      at org.jboss.modcluster.container.jbossweb.JBossWebContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(JBossWebContext.j
ava:48)
13:54:12,242 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)      at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java
:169)
13:54:12,242 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
13:54:12,242 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)      at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
13:54:12,242 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
13:54:12,257 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)      at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:372)
13:54:12,257 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)      at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
13:54:12,257 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)      at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:679)
13:54:12,257 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:931)
13:54:12,257 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
13:54:12,257 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Operation failed with status WAITING
13:54:12,257 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)      at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.IoFutureHelper.get(IoFutureHelper.java:89)
13:54:12,257 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)      at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.NamingStoreCache.getRemoteNamingStore(NamingStoreCache.java:56)
13:54:12,257 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)      at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getOrCreateCachedNamingStore(InitialContextFacto
ry.java:166)
13:54:12,257 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)      at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getOrCreateNamingStore(InitialContextFactory.jav
a:139)
13:54:12,273 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)      at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactory.java:104
)
13:54:12,273 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)      ... 22 more
```

This is the code before and up to line 75 (referenced in the stack trace). It's borrowed from a previous test, so I have some reason to believe it should work.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");

properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://127.0.0.1:4447");
properties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "user");
properties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "pwd");

ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = null;
Destination destination = null;

try {
    Context context = new InitialContext(properties);
```

So a few questions:
1) Can you see anything that I need to do differently in this servlet to connect to the queue?
2) Is there documentation for valid other values where I have "remote://"?
3) Presumably the port where I have 4447 needs to match something in the JBOSS config - is there documentation around that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Factory, URL and security principles being passed to `InitialContext` are only required when performing a JNDI lookup from outside the server.

If the war containing your test servlet is being deployed inside the same server that has the queues configured then you should be able to just instantiate a new `InitialContext()` without any properties to perform a lookup against the local JDNI instance.

```
try {
    Context context = new InitialContext();
```

Comment: It appears that I get the same exception if I do this. Is there a different string I should pass in for the factory class in this case? And if so, is there documentation around those?

Comment: You should not need to pass the factory. Just instantiate a new `InitialContext()` without any parameters at all from inside your Servlet code. The JBoss container will return the `Context` that you can then use to lookup your JMS Queue.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying no property object at all, and I was getting the same exception

Comment: I wrote a small test servet and instantiated InitialContext() from inside the servlet, then obtained a jms connection factory and so on, and it all works as expected. Your issue must be elsewhere. Are you sure you have redeployed the new code?